# npm copyfiles not correct target path

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, build-script

I'm using the npm package "copyfiles" in my buildscript. 
But the target directory is not that what I expected.

```
"copy-template": "copyfiles \"./src/**/*.html\" \"dist\"",
```

My **base directory** structure is:

```
src/pages/.../htmlfiles
```

What I want is:

```
dist/pages/.../htmlfiles
```

so the same structure as before without "src"
In the moment I have always the src directory in my dist folder.

```
dist/src/pages/../htmlfiles
```

Maybe you have some hints for me?

Best David

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your script as follows:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "copy-template": "copyfiles -u 1 \"./src/**/*.html\" \"dist\"",
  ...
},
...
```

Note, the addition of the `--up` or `-u` option as explained in the [docs](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/copyfiles#command-line).